# Firebase querying if name matches the password on login with java

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm currently building an app, with a Login-Activity. When the user registers himself he has to give a Name and a password. If he wants to Login I want to make it possible, that the user can Login with the name and his password. How do I proof if the name matching to the password?
That's what I got so far:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    db.collection("Users").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        QueryDocumentSnapshot document = null;
                        for (document : task.getResult()){
                             document.getString("Name");
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Firebase Compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) to get name and password matching with the data given from the Login page.

You can use the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

db.collection("Users")
        .whereEqualTo("password",password)
        .whereEqualTo("name",name")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener({task ->
                         if(task.isSuccessful){
                            val result = task.result                 
                        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying all the documents of users collection you can set a whereEqualTo clause and pass the condition to find the documents which have the same name and password as entered by the user.

Do note that the length of result array of document snapshot would be one (if no duplicate accounts present) if credentials are matching or zero if there are no such record.

For this you should put indexes on the name and password field to make it faster to execute the query. Here is the link to querying in firestore and indexing

[Firestore Querying operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#java_7)

Comment: Mark this answer as correct if it solved your query. Thank you

Comment: of course. I'm still trying to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: what is the condition to find the documents, with the matching Password to the name?

Comment: Please refer to the answer by @Nibrass H just above